# Estimate argmax of function that is measured at discrete points

Tags: curve-fitting, extreme-value, discrete-data

I have gathered simulation data of a function $f(x)$, where $x$ is a continuous variable. I measure $f$ at discrete points $x_k$. Since the underlying process is stochastic, I performed Monte Carlo simulations, and computed the mean of the function over several independent trials (seeds) (see the figure, left is the mean, right the different seeds). [image: figure]

I am interested in the value of $x^*$ that maximises $f(x)$ on the given domain. Now, normally I would try to fit a curve to either the average quantity or each separate instance, however in this particular case I cannot find a function that fits the data. Additionally, I can imagine that finding a function that fits the data is in general either difficult or impossible. Where I can crudely estimate $x^*$ by simply computing the mean value of each separate instance, i.e. $x^* \approx 1/N \sum_i^N x^*_i$, I have a feeling that this is either wrong on inaccurate.

What method can generate an estimate of the value of $x^*$ that approximately maximises $f(x)$? If possible, I would like to have an estimate that includes error, i.e. that I know that $x^* = x_0 \pm \epsilon$.

Any source, direction guidelines or other help is greatly appreciated!

---

To help with this particular example, the data points are the following:

```
x = [1.05 1.1  1.15 1.2  1.25 1.3  1.35 1.4  1.45 1.5  1.55 1.6  1.65 1.7 1.75 1.8  1.85 1.9  1.95 2.  ]
f_x = [2.289e-09 7.491e-04 1.249e-02 3.193e-02 5.061e-02 6.281e-02 6.701e-02
       6.735e-02 6.625e-02 6.451e-02 6.225e-02 5.955e-02 5.683e-02 5.384e-02
       5.095e-02 4.811e-02 4.530e-02 4.238e-02 3.983e-02 3.727e-02]
```

and the function values for each separate seed instance [can be found on this Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/d9PUm3S2) (if needed).

Comment: You might be overthinking this. On the right you exhibit the results of (presumably) independent trials.  Each one yields an estimate of $x^{*}.$  That gives the *Monte-Carlo distribution of $x^{*}.$*  Use it the same way you would use the MC distribution of any estimate.  For instance, report its mean and its standard error.

Comment: Is the estimate of $x^*$ just the (discrete valued) value of $x$ for which each independent trial is maximised?